# Compress PSD and AI files on client side (javascript) on uploading

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jszip

I’m publishing posts (with PSD files), these files are very large in size, so I tried to compress them once I upload the file (and before publishing the post), I used jszip package and it worked for me but unfortunately I can't modify the FileList() object to assign the new compressed file to the file field without using (Data Transfer) which is not supported in Safari and IE.

```
let zip = new JSZIP()
zip.file(filename, file_input_field.files[0])
zip.generateAsync({type:"blob"}).then((blobdata)=>{
let zipblob=new DataTransfer();
let zip_file=new File([zipblob], “filename.zip”);
list.items.add(zip_file);
let myFileList = list.files;
file_input_field.files = myFileList
```

I appreciate you help!

Answer (score 1):

The `files` attribute is a [FileList object](https://w3c.github.io/FileAPI/#filelist-section), you can't modify it.

In your case I would use the FormData interface and send the form asynchronously. You've a clear example at this page: [Using FormData Objects - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects#sending_files_using_a_formdata_object).

In the example they use `XMLHttpRequest` but you can also use the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API). See also: [Using Fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#uploading_a_file).